# CSS Style strangely rendered depending on device

Tags: ios, css, colors, kendo-ui, rendering

I'm building a stand-alone application.

The problem is that when I deploy on my webserver, then test it on a desktop browser, everything's fine, not on my mobile device (IPad): the colors are different (yeah, I'm stuck because of colors -.-).
I tried with different browsers - same results.

I use the mobile.ios.css file for my app. So, per example, with the ios stylesheet you got the default blue gradient navbar with the white text for the title (ok on desktop browser). On my Ipad it renders a gray/white gradient instead of the blue and the title is a deeper gray with some shadow. It seems to be the default style of the navbar, but why is it working on a desktop then?

I used the theme builder offered on the kendo ui website to fix it up, but it failed.

I think this issue belongs to the javascript behind kendo framework.

Anybody got an idea or went through some similar difficulties?

Comment: post your CSS, mobile.ios.css

Comment: We need code, as that's where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo UI Mobile shows slightly different styling on iPhone and iPad, to better blend in as a native-like application. There are also differences between iOS versions (e.g. the Switch is different between 4 and 5 and the TabStrip between 5 and 6).

If you prefer the same styling everywhere, you can force the platform in your application - [check the docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#force-ios-5-look) for how to do it.

Comment: Perfect! Simple as that! Thank you!
Now I could change the "right" CSS classes since even on my desktop browser, I could see the CSS rendered into my tablet.

Comment: Well, you can set tablet to false.